# Highlight active li in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

```
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar" role="navigation">
        <div class="list-group">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Home</a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">Quem-somos</a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item">FAQ</a>
        </div>
      </div><!--/span-->
    </div><!--/row-->
```

I have this code above, and i want highlight the current page with the danger color, but the .active class it's blue in this particular code.

I already try setup in my stylesheet:

```
.active {
 background-color: red;
}
```

but has no effect

Comment: Make your selector more specific. Specificity is key in css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could force the override with `!important` like so:

```
.active {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Even though specifying `!important` will work, this is is bad practice as it stops the css cascading and will probably cause more problems than it fixes.  All you need to do is to be more specific with your selector.

```
.list-group a.active { background-color: red;}
```

See my [Example](http://www.bootply.com/Xf2w5JHJhR)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
a.list-group-item.active {
        background: red;
    }
```